# AWS S3 Heroku nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, heroku

I am running a nodejs application hosted on heroku where I want to be able to upload selected photos to AWS S3. I followed all the steps heroku gave, but am finding this error: "MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'Bucket' in params"

Here's my code:

index.js

```
app.get('/sign-s3', (req, res) => {
const s3 = new aws.S3();
const fileName = req.query['file-name'];
const fileType = req.query['file-type'];
console.log(fileName, fileType)
const s3Params = {
    Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
    Key: fileName,
    Expires: 60,
    ContentType: fileType,
    ACL: 'public-read'
};

s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.end();
    }
    const returnData = {
        signedRequest: data,
        url: `https://${S3_BUCKET}.s3.amazonaws.com/${fileName}`
    };
    res.write(JSON.stringify(returnData));
    res.end();
  

  });
});

app.post('/save-details', (req, res) => {

    res.send(req.body.username)
    console.log(req.body.username)

});
```

here's my front end scripts

testing.ejs

```
 <input type="file" id="file-input">
    <p id="status">Please select a file</p>
    <img style="border:1px solid gray;width:300px;"  id="preview" src="/images/default.png">

    <h2>Your information</h2>

    <form method="POST" action="/save-details">
      <input type="hidden" id="avatar-url" name="avatar-url" value="/images/default.png">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
      <input type="text" name="full-name" placeholder="Full name"><br><br>

      <hr>
      <h2>Save changes</h2>

      <input type="submit" value="Update profile">
    </form>


    <script>

    /*
      Function to carry out the actual PUT request to S3 using the signed request from the app.
    */
    function uploadFile(file, signedRequest, url){
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('PUT', signedRequest);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if(xhr.readyState === 4){
          if(xhr.status === 200){
            document.getElementById('preview').src = url;
            document.getElementById('avatar-url').value = url;
          }
          else{
            alert('Could not upload file.');
          }
        }
      };
      xhr.send(file);
    }

    /*
      Function to get the temporary signed request from the app.
      If request successful, continue to upload the file using this signed
      request.
    */
    function getSignedRequest(file){
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', `/sign-s3?file-name=${file.name}&file-type=${file.type}`);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if(xhr.readyState === 4){
          if(xhr.status === 200){
            const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            uploadFile(file, response.signedRequest, response.url);
          }
          else{
            alert('Could not get signed URL.');
          }
        }
      };
      xhr.send();
    }

    /*
     Function called when file input updated. If there is a file selected, then
     start upload procedure by asking for a signed request from the app.
    */
    function initUpload(){
      const files = document.getElementById('file-input').files;
      const file = files[0];
      if(file == null){
        return alert('No file selected.');
      }
      getSignedRequest(file);
    }

    /*
     Bind listeners when the page loads.
    */
    (() => {
        document.getElementById('file-input').onchange = initUpload;
    })();

    </script>
```

hopefully this helps, and thanks in advance.

Comment: `S3_BUCKET` should probably be `process.env.S3_BUCKET`?

Comment: actually had that already declared, it was just outside the function.

Comment: Are you getting this error on the server-side, or the client-side?